# How to get a reference to the list returned by Perl's grep?

Tags: perl

I would like to use the `grep` function to filter a list of values and store a reference to the filtered list into a hash. What I am after is something like:

```
my $allValues = [
    'a',
    'unwanted value',
    'b',
    'c',
];

$stuff = {
    'values' => grep { $_ ne 'unwanted value' } @$allValues
};
```

Only, when I try that, the `%$stuff` hash is:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'b' => 'c',
          'values' => 'a'
        };
```

Is there a way to fix the anonymous hash-creating code so that I instead get:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'values' => [
                        'a',
                        'b',
                        'c'
                      ]
        };
```

But not by creating a local variable or calling a subroutine (in other words, all in-line)?

Comment: You can't have a reference to a list in Perl. You can only have a reference to an array.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try with:

```
$stuff = {
    'values' => [ grep { $_ ne 'unwanted value' } @$allValues ]
};
```

Comment: How does this work? Does this solution just return reference to the result of grep or it reallocate memory for the entire array? I worry about performance.